# Is there a consensus about the relationsship between tax rate and tax revenue?

Tags: taxation, optimal-taxation

I have been looking at these charts by the Mercator think tank which describe tax revenue and tax rate as percentage of GDP for the United States.

[Mercator think tank](https://www.mercatus.org/publications/government-spending/tax-rates-vs-tax-revenues)

[image: Federal revenue & top tax rate]

[image: Federal revenue & top average tax rate]

Is there a consensus about the relationship between tax rate and tax revenue on a global scale?

Comment: Even from the limited data shown in your graph we can see that there isn't *a* tax rate but many. Your graphs show that decreasing the marginal tax rate for earners the **top bracket** did not reduce the federal tax revenue (as % of GDP), quite likely because the **average** marginal rate at the same time went up, meaning earners in lower brackets had to pick up more of the tab. So can you please clarify your question: what type of tax rate and what type of tax revenue are you talking about?

Comment: P.s.: given the above, the labeling of the first graph by Mercator is misleading, so I would probably try to validate their data from a different source as well.